# Increment number and if statement on same function in Liquid

Tags: liquid

I have a form on my website where the user adds fields dynamically. I've created the same function 100 times but only changed the incrementing number as you can see below. I need to create a loop for the incrementing number but also leave the if statement in case the field is blank.

Here's my Liquid code:

```
{% if data.sku0 != null %} <tr bgcolor="#ffffff"><th><a href="http://{{data.host}}/ProductDetails.asp?ProductCode={{data.sku0}}" style="font-size:12px;"><img src="http://{{data.host}}/v/vspfiles/photos/{{data.sku0}}-2s.jpg" width="50px" height="50px"></a></th><td>{{data.0qty}} x {{data.sku0}} - {{data.0item}} - {{data.0price}} each</td></tr>{% endif %}

{% if data.sku1 != null %} <tr bgcolor="#ffffff"><th><a href="http://{{data.host}}/ProductDetails.asp?ProductCode={{data.sku1}}" style="font-size:12px;"><img src="http://{{data.host}}/v/vspfiles/photos/{{data.sku1}}-2s.jpg" width="50px" height="50px"></a></th><td>{{data.1qty}} x {{data.sku1}} - {{data.1item}} - {{data.1price}} each</td></tr>{% endif %}

{% if data.sku2 != null %} <tr bgcolor="#ffffff"><th><a href="http://{{data.host}}/ProductDetails.asp?ProductCode={{data.sku2}}" style="font-size:12px;"><img src="http://{{data.host}}/v/vspfiles/photos/{{data.sku2}}-2s.jpg" width="50px" height="50px"></a></th><td>{{data.2qty}} x {{data.sku2}} - {{data.2item}} - {{data.2price}} each</td></tr>{% endif %}

// and so on... up to 100 (I need it to increase for as long as its needed, not limited to 100).
// notice that I have a increasing number for a few elements such as {{sku}}, {{name}}, {{item}}, etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of what you're trying to achieve but something like that might work (not tested) :

```
{% for i in (0..100) %}
  {%- capture sku_index -%}sku{{ forloop.index }}{%- endcapture -%}
  {% unless data[sku_index] == blank %}
    Your stuff
  {% else %}
    {% continue %}
  {% endunless %}
{% endfor %}
```